# How to create side menu in xamarin.forms xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to create a Side menu bar its always opened. If i use master detail page then its behavior is change, How to adjust masterdetail page.
Please have a look screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're after, but you could still use Master Detail page ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#controlling-the-detail-page-display-behavior)) with *Split* option set as as the behavior `MasterBehavior="Split"`.

EDIT

If you don't want to use Master Detail page, just go with standard `Grid` with two columns. The layout could look like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Column="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding YourMenuItems}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource YourMenuItemTemplate}"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <!--The content that goes on the right side-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is there any other option for creating this screen?

Comment: Its not working
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MSCommunity_Xamarin"
             x:Class="NavigationMasterDetail.MainPage"
             MasterBehavior="Split">

Comment: @Parmendra I edited my answer, to show a different approach

Comment: Thanks you, It am going to implement

Comment: @Parmendra No worries. Please mark this as an answer to your question, if it provides a solution to your problem. Thanks

Comment: @Ali, I am new in Xamarin, I am still not solve this issue can you please add few label in above code, please you can use direct put the value in xaml.

Comment: @Parmendra Sorry mate, this is not how it works. If you don't know how to start with this, check some tutorials etc. A good point for starting with Xamarin would be [Xamarin University](https://university.xamarin.com/classes/track/self-guided)

Comment: just a note "The value of the FlyoutLayoutBehavior property only affects applications running on tablets or the desktop. Applications running on phones always have the Popover behavior."